# git checkout of remote branch does not give latest version?

Tags: git

I would think that git checkout -b mylocal origin/develop would mean that mylocal would have the latest code from the remote server but it does not (git log does not show commits that I know are on the remote server) -- it is only after a subsequent pull that mylocal has all those commits. Is this to be expected?

Comment: Yes. You need to do a git fetch or git pull to get the most recent changes from the remote

Comment: You can try with `git pull`

Comment: When in doubt I use [this git cheat sheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html).  Click on every section to see the relevant commands

Answer (score 2):

This is to be expected, yes.

You need to understand that `origin/develop` is **not** the branch *develop* on the remote server but **your local copy** of the *develop* branch on the remote server. This means, you need to update your local copies of remote branches using `git fetch` before you see new changes.

Comment: so *the very first time*, i would get the latest but for subsequent checkouts i get the local version, right?

Comment: If by `the very first time` you mean `git clone` then yes, cloning fetches the latest state. All changes made remotely after your `git clone` or any later `git fetch` or `git pull` are not visible to you until you `git fetch` or `git pull` again, this includes commits, branches, tags, and so on.

Comment: is there any difference between git fetch or pull in this context and would the sequence be, as I used, git checkout -b mylocal origin/develop followed by git pull or git fetch? can i also git checkout origin/develop git fetch and then git checkout -b mylocal origin/develop (or git pull instead of git fetch) and are there any circumstances where these various ways are not completely equivalent in terms of results?

Comment: `git checkout -b mylocal origin/develop` followed by `git fetch` won't work as the branch `mylocal` does not get updated when `origin/develop` does. Fetch first, then create the branch. "can i also git checkout origin/develop git fetch and then git checkout -b mylocal origin/develop" you can, but you don't need to checkout that branch. `git fetch` and `git checkout -b mylocal origin/develop` does the correct thing.